# How to insert a HashMap into a database in java

Tags: java

I am trying to insert my HashMap into an Access database but I keep getting errors.
 Here is my code:

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry : mapImpedanceAll.entrySet()) {
    prep1 = entry.getKey().replaceAll("\\s", "_");
    prep1=prep1.replace(":","");
    prep1=prep1.replace("<","LessThan");
    prep1=prep1.replaceAll("\\." ,"");
    prep1=prep1.replaceAll("\\(s\\)" ,"");
    prep1=prep1.replaceAll(",$" ,"");
    prep1=prep1.replaceAll("%" ,"");
    prep1=prep1.replace("-" ,"_");
    prep1=prep1.replace("_" ,"");

    if(dbColNames.contains(prep1)) {
        try {
            Statement qu = null;
            qu =conn.createStatement();
            String stg = "INSERT INTO Impedance2 "+prep1+" VALUES('"+entry.getValue()+"')";
            qu.execute(stg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the error:

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.4 row column
>   count mismatch

I'm sure it is something to do with the statement `String stg = "INSERT INTO Impedance2 "+prep1+" VALUES('"+entry.getValue()+"')";` but I've played around with it and it still trips up.

`dbColNames` is an array of existing database column names so I can check against them before adding the HashMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code tries to do the following:
For each entry in the hash map, *if* there is a table column available with name equal to key name, you try to insert this value into the database.

However, your generated INSERT statement does not consider the other columns in your table. You would need something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (NULL, value, NULL, NULL)
```

to get this working at all (unless you have appropriate defaults defined for your columns), where you place the hashmap value at the appropriate index in the statement and fill up all the other columns with NULL (or an appropriate default value; NULL values might even not be allowed).

If your hashmap shall represent one single data set, you need to combine all data into one single INSERT statement:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ("
           + hashmap.get("col1") + ", " + hashmap.get("col2") + ", "
           + hashmap.get("col3") + ", " + hashmap.get("col4") + ");";
```

I left out checking for if values are available at all, additionally, using a StringBuffer would be more efficient. If you do this more than once, consider using a prepared statement instead.